# shotgun_api3 not working in PyInstaller exe build

Tags: python, pyinstaller, xmlrpclib

This is my run.py file, it works perfectly fine if you run it manually with something like `py -3 run.py`

```
import shotgun_api3
```

I use Python 3 to build the .exe using PyInstaller:

```
py -3 -m PyInstaller run.py
```

The build completes successfully. When I try to run the .exe I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmlrpc'
```

So I tried adding `import xmlrpc` above the `import shotgun_api3` in my `run.py`, then the error changed to this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmlrpc.client'
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the best solution, but I managed to build the executable. I had to remove httplib2 and six from shotgun api, pip-installed them by myself and updated imports in shotgun.py.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add them as hidden imports as well as a few others:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import urllib2 --hidden-import xmlrpc --hidden-import xmlrpc.client --hidden-import xmlrpclib --hidden-import cookielib main.py
```